# Azure Batch VNet Integration - Failing to provision nodes

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-batch

I'm trying to provision a Pool of Nodes within Azure Batch and have the nodes join an existing VNet that has other applications sitting inside of it, to no avail...

I have a subnet created and delegated to Azure Batch.

The pool tries to resize and during the first minute or so, it creates the Public IP, Network Security Group and the Load Balancer (all sounds good!). As it reaches the end of the resize timeout duration, those 3 components start to roll-back and get deleted, and the pool never resizes. I'm only trying to provision 1 node in this instance for the purpose of testing.

I'm getting this error in my Resource Group Activity Log each time it tries to provision the nodes, but don't know exactly what it means, nor how to resolve it.
`"errorMessage": "The user did not have permissions to GET the AuditIfNotExists policy's target type 'Microsoft.Security/complianceResults'."` It seems to get this error when trying to write to `Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses`.

Other info about setup:

- Batch Account Pool Type: Batch Service
- Pool Image: Marketplace - ubuntu-server-container 16-04 Customer
- Container configuration - pulling down Container from ACR Node size: Standard A1_V2 (have tried several others also)
- Dedicated nodes: 1
- VNet: Existing VNet with dedicated subnet delegated to Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts

Any advice welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up filing a support ticket with Microsoft over this.

Turns out the issue was due to subnet I had chosen. I made the unfortunate mistake of delegating it to Batch Account and it should not be. `ResourceNotPermittedOnDelegatedSubnet` was the exact exception that was firing in the background.

Nowhere on the portal was I able to access the exception that the support guy had access to though. Nor does the documentation state it mustn't be a delegated subnet.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Cool, if that’s the answer which suffice your question then I would recommend marking it as answer.